# Lucee not showing run-time errors

Tags: runtime-error, cfml, lucee

Running Lucee server 5.2.1.9 (hosted at Vivio), and I'm unable to get it to show any run-time errors.

- I have debugging enabled
- I have enabled all debug info types
- I've set a debug template (for all IPs); currently set to "Classic", but I've tried "Comment" and "Modern" as well.

When an error occurs, I get an empty page. If a debug template set, I get dumps of all the appropriate scopes and DB activity, as well as execution times... but no error message/details or stack trace.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

How do I insure Lucee displays my run-time errors during development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you every figured this out (kind of a necro). If you are in Dev disect your application.cfc. I had an issue in my onRequest section. Someone threw a cftry around the target page include. This ran Lucee into the catch and it showed a blank page.

If that doesn't help try removing your OnError function in there. There might be something in there that is trying to serve up a friendly error page which could prevent error output.

Also, look in Lucee server administrator and check that it is pointing to the native error.cfm that comes with the Lucee package.

I have to add it even though it isn't likely the cause. Search your code for any abort. It could be someone was testing a routine and was aborting to see how far Lucee was processing.

Hope these suggestions help.

Comment: There was, indeed, something wrong with my Application.cfc. Quite likely something throwing an error in the OnRequest section. I solved way back when by recreating my Application.cfc from scratch.  :-o